# select, insert and loop for rows in cronjob

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a small giveaway table and I need cronjobs in MySQL to make it automatic.

**giveaways_participants table**

*This is where your user id gets added when you participate in a giveaway.*

```
id    |    user_id    |    giveaway_id
__________________________
 1    |   1           |    4
 2    |   67          |    39
```

**giveaways table**

*All giveaways available*

```
id  |  user_id  |  contents  | expires 
__________________________
 1    |   1   |  4,189,45,7  |  1512484213
 2    |   67   |  39  |  1512484213
 3    |   67   |  8,2,645  |  1512484213
```

**inventory table**

*The users inventory*

```
id  |  user_id  |  item_id
__________________________
 1    |   1   |  4
 2    |   67   |  2
 3    |   67   |  7
```

I want the cronjob to daily go through `giveaways` that have expired (ended), pick a random winner from `giveaways_participants` for that specific giveaway and insert the `contents` from `giveaways` into `inventory` as a new row for every item separated by a comma for that user.

How can this be achieved in the most efficient way possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a php page (if it's possible for you) which can be called from crontab, like php dailyga.php.
What would be in that page? Select from giveaway's table, which data has just expired and pick it's id. Then select all ids from your users and pick random one, then insert into inventory that user's ID and giveaway ID. 
Setting a cron job for every morning would do the job (or midnight etc.).
How to pick just expired giveaway? Just select those which expiry date is in the past (even a minute), but the youngest - or the one for which there is no entry in inventory table.
Hope I helped a little.

Comment: It has to be done without someone loading the page to execute the php script, that's the problem.

Comment: But you can process the script in php cli from crontab.

Comment: For example, the cron entry can be:
`0 9 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/www/dailyga.php > /dev/null/ 2>&1`
By this, php will run your page every day at 9am and will not save any errors, if appeared, anywhere.